# how to get latest foreign key value in models.py

Tags: django

I have a little problem with getting latest foreign key value in my django app. Here are my two models:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    ...

class Dividend(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('pay date')
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name="dividends")
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["date"]
```

I would like to get latest dividend from stock object. So basically this - `stock.dividends.latest('date')`. However, everytime I call `stock.dividends.latest('date')`, it fires up sql query to get latest dividend. I have latest() method in for cycle for every stock I have. I would like to avoid these sql queries. May I somehow define new method in `class Stock` that would get latest dividend within sql query for stock object?
I cannot change default ordering from "date" to "-date".
Using `select_related('dividends')` loads dividends objects with stock, but latest probably uses order_by and it requires sql query anyway. :(

---

**EDIT1**: To make more clear what I want, here is an example. Let's say I have 100 symbols in shares.keys():

```
for stock in Stock.objects.filter(symbol__in=shares.keys()): # 1 sql query
    latest_dividend = stock.dividends.latest('date')                    # 100 sql queries
    ... #do something with latest dividend
```

Well and in some cases I might have 500 symbols in shares.keys(). That is why I need to avoid making sql queries on getting latest dividend for stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure my solution is the best, but here it is (works only with PostgreSQL):

```
stocks = list(Stock.objects.filter(**something))
dividends = Dividend.objects.filter(
    stock__in=stocks,
).order_by(
    'stock_id',
    '-date'
).distinct(
    'stock_id',
)

dividends_dict = {d.stock_id: d for d in dividends}

for stock in stocks:
    stock.latest_dividend = dividends_dict.get(stock.id)
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I altered it a little bit in my answer. What a shame queryset can not do [-1] :P

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with you, so I tested many Django queries. Finally, I found out that we can use this:

```
Stock.objects.all().annotate(latest_date=Max('dividends__date')).filter(dividends__date=F('latest_date')).values('dividends')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, I'm assuming you are trying to access the dividends from your stock object in order to limit your queries to the database. I believe that is the least number queries of possible.

```
 stock_options = stock.objects.get(pk=your_query)
 order_options = stock.dividend_set.order_by('-date')[:5]
```

Comment: hi, I added example code to the question named EDIT1. Your code does the same as .latest('date'). Order_by() creates sql query every time. Thanks for answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

likeon: Thanks for your answer. But I think I can avoid initializing that large dictionary (I have 5000 stocks and 280 000 dividends). But your list gave me an idea. Your code requires 2 sql queries. Here is my example (EDIT1).

```
for stock in Stock.objects.filter(symbol__in=shares.keys())\
                          .prefetch_related('dividends'): # 2 sql queries
    latest_dividend = list(stock.dividends.all())[-1]     # 0 sql queries
    ... #do something with latest_dividend
```

My code also requires 2 sql queries, but I do not have to reorder it and create list from stocks and all 280 000 dividends (I only create dict from current stock dividends every cycle). May be creating one dict is quicker than creating len(shares.keys()) dicts, not sure.

I thought there would be easier solution (avoid creating list/dictionary from dividends), but this is good enough for now. Thanks for answers!

Comment: 1. The whole point of converting Stock queryset to list is about possibility to assign last dividend as stock attribute (to use in template). That's not really required.

2. Distinct in my answer makes sure you are getting only required dividends. One latest per each stock instance (if it's exists). Your code on other hand takes them all.

Comment: @likeon hm, distinct does not get only latest dividend per stock: http://pastebin.com/MwebMDz1 To create dividends_dict it takes 5.6 seconds. Not very usable for web app.

Comment: well, creating list by prefetching takes even longer - http://pastebin.com/ZCdcH3N4 I'll mark your answer as better.

Comment: Distinct should be only on stock_id. My bad. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understood you can do it this way:

```
stock.dividends.last()
```

as implementation in Django is like this:

```
    def first(self):
    """Return the first object of a query or None if no match is found."""
    for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
        return obj
```

Also, you can use `.latest(*fields, field_name=None)` too.