# Django DB Query for nested models

Tags: mysql, django

I have 3 models in my project: User, Device and Report.  A user can own several Devices and each Device will provide several Reports. I want to find the latest report for each device for the currently logged in user.  My models are currently:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_id


class Report(models.Model):
    device_id = models.ForeignKey('Device', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coordinates = models.JSONField(null=True)
    fill = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.device_id)
```

This query returns all of the Devices and their associated Reports for the logged in user:

```
device_list = Report.objects.filter(device_id__owner__username=request.user)
```

I'm having difficulty in filtering for only the latest report from each device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get latest foreign key value in models.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137378/how-to-get-latest-foreign-key-value-in-models-py)

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. Even though it is probably not optimal, if you're in a bind trying to do something like this, here it is:

First I got a list of `Devices` owned by the logged in user:

```
device_list = list(set(Device.objects.filter(owner__username=request.user).values_list('pk', flat=True)))
```

I then iterated over that list to find the latest entry for each `Device` and built a list of last entries for each `Device`:

```
response_list = []
for device in device_list:
    last_dev_report = Report.objects.filter(device_id=device).last()
    response_list.append(last_dev_report)
```

I was then able to pass `response_list` to my `.html` and build a table of the latest `Reports` from each `Device`.

This requires multiple DB hits, so it's likely not ideal for large DBs, but I'm not expecting a user/owner to have many devices.